# How do I search for words similar to other words?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string

I am looking to make a small script in Node.js that will match words with another word that is similar. For example I am searching for `***ing` and I have an array like `['loving', 'mating', 'cats', 'wording']` then I would expect it to return `['loving', 'mating']` and exclude `['cats']` (because it does not end in *ing*), and `['wording']` (because it is seven characters and not six.).

This is my current *not* working code that I have written.

```
let foundWords = [];
for (let i = 0, len = wordList.length; i < len; i++) {
  for (let j = 0, len = wordList[i].split('').length; j < len; j++) {
    if (wordToFind.charAt(j) == '*') {
      return;
    };
    if (wordToFind.charAt(j) === wordList[i].charAt(j)) {
      if (foundWords.includes(wordList[i]) == false) {
        foundWords.push(wordList[i]);
      };
    }
  }  
}
console.log(foundWords);
```

The objective of writing this code is to allow me to brute force with a dictionary list all the combinations for this *cryptogram* and the words inside.

[image: cryptogram sheet]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) along with a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

To construct the regex you will need to replace your wildcard characters `*` with the wildcard character of a regex: `.`. Then add `^` and `$` to anchor the regex to match all the way from the beginning to the end of the string.

```js
function filterMatches(needle, haystack) {
  const regex = new RegExp('^' + needle.replace(/\*/g, '.') + '$');
  return haystack.filter(word => regex.test(word));
}

console.log(filterMatches('***ing', ['loving', 'mating', 'cats', 'wording']));
```

Answer (score 4):

i really recommend you to read about  **Levenshtein distance**
sound exactly like what you trying to achieve here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Example

an implementation in java script also
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#JavaScript

> in information theory and computer science, the Levenshtein distance
>   is a metric for measuring the amount of difference between two
>   sequences (i.e. an edit distance). The Levenshtein distance between
>   two strings is defined as the minimum number of edits needed to
>   transform one string into the other, with the allowable edit
>   operations being insertion, deletion, or substitution of a single
>   character.
>
> Example The Levenshtein distance between "kitten" and "sitting" is 3, 
>   since the following three edits change one into the other,  and there
>   isn't a way to do it with fewer than three edits:
>
> kitten   sitten   (substitution of 'k' with 's')
>
> sitten   sittin   (substitution of 'e' with 'i')
>
> sittin   sitting   (insert 'g' at the end).

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think this should work. If you are not understanding a part try to look up the `String.prototype` functions at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf). It really helps to know some of these functions since it will make you code more easy.

```js
let input = '***ing';
let inputLength = input.length
let results = [];

while (input.charAt(0) === "*") {
  input = input.substr(1);
}

const arr = ['loving', 'mating', 'cats', 'wording'];


for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

  if (inputLength != arr[i].length) {
    continue;
  }

  if(arr[i].indexOf(input) != -1) {
    results.push(arr[i]);
  }
}

console.log(results);
```

Comment: btw although this works use 4castle solution, much more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be like;

```js
function getMatches(ts, ss){
  var es = ts.split(/\*+/)[1]; // or ts.match(/[^\*]+$/)[0];
  return ss.filter(s => s.endsWith(es) && s.length === ts.length)
}

var res = getMatches("***ing",['loving', 'mating', 'cats', 'wording']);
console.log(res);
```